# css - Strictly set style?

Tags: css

In my CSS, I have this:

```
b {
  color: Red;
}
```

And in my body:

```
<b>Hello world!</b>
```

As a result, I get "Hello world!" text that is red in color.

However, as I add more classes:

```
.myClass {
  color: Blue;
}
.green {
  color: Green;
}
```

And I modify my body:

```
<b>H<a class="myClass">ell</a><a class="green">o</a> wo<a style="color: Black;">rl</a>d
```

I will not get the same result as earlier.

Is there a way to *strictly* set a CSS style? Which means that with the above code I wish to get "Hello world!" text that is red.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of **[CSS Specificicty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**

> **The concept:** Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which
>   property values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be
>   applied. Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are
>   composed of selectors of different sorts.

Inline styles override external CSS, and class selectors override element level selectors.

> The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:

1. Universal selectors
2. Type selectors <--- your `b` CSS
3. Class selectors <---- your `.xyz` CSS
4. Attributes selectors
5. Pseudo-classes
6. ID selectors
7. Inline style <--- your `style=''`

If you wish to override specificity, you can use `!important` after the rule in question, e.g.:

```
b {
  color: Red !important;
}
```

However, this is not recommended, instead you should write 'better' rules (more specific) to target your HTML as appropriate. This ensures you end up with better structured code, the issue with `!important` being it can lead to unforeseen circumstances where rules aren't working because you may have forgot you had previously overridden them.

Again, from MDN:

> **The !important exception**
>
> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
>   debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets.
>
> **Some rules of thumb**
>
> Never use !important on site-wide css. Only use !important on
>   page-specific css that overrides site-wide or foreign css (from ExtJs
>   or YUI for example). Never use !important when you're writing a
>   plugin/mashup. Always look for a way to use specificity before even
>   considering !important

Comment: So u're saying it is impossible?

Comment: You can use the !important rule, or increase specificity

Comment: @chris97ong `!important` works you although have to set it on the `<a>` tag to override the class rules : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wPUZj/4/

Comment: The code in the question is not affected by specificity at all. The reason why “ell” is blue is that it is in an element to which `color: Blue` has been set. There is no other rule that applies to that element, so there is no conflict to be resolved by specificity.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/SM58Q/1/ - if you add a rule with more specificity, it is overridden, e.g. `b .myClass{
    color:red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

With the markup that you provided, no. Otherwise, maybe

The inline style has priority over the stylesheet so part of the text will be black no matter what.  You might be able to create a rule that has enough specificity that it will take precendence over any other rules.

```
b, b .myClass, b .green {
     color: red;
 }
```

Though this can get troublesome to maintain.  And there is still a chance that a different css rule will get higher precedence later on. I am not completely sure that even specifying all the children with * will do it.

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks, I wasn't 100% either way.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking whether you can set a property (`color` in the example) on an element in a manner that will not be overridden by settings on inner elements.

You cannot do that with settings on the element itself. But you can set a property on an element and all of its descendants:

```
b, b * {
  color: Red !important;
}
```

This will override any normal settings for `color` on inner elements. But it is ineffective against, say, `.green { color: Green !important; }`. To defeat that, you would need a more specific selector, such as `b .green`, for your rule—so there is no *general* way to achieve that (i.e., a way that is independent of the specific markup used inside the element).